# Apple App Rejection reason

Tags: objective-c, ios, universal

> We found that your app does not comply with the Apple iOS Human
>   Interface Guidelines, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, we noticed your app only supported the top up variant of
>   the portrait orientation, but not the bottom up variation.
>
> While supporting both variants of both orientations, each with unique
>   launch images, provides the best user experience and is recommended,
>   we understand there are certain applications that must run in the
>   portrait orientation only. In this case, it would be appropriate to
>   support both variants of that orientation in your application, e.g.,
>   Home button up and down.
>
> Addressing this issue typically requires only a simple and
>   straightforward code modification. However, if you require assistance,
>   the Apple Developer Support Team is available to provide code-level
>   assistance.
>
> For more information, please review the Aim to Support All
>   Orientations section of the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

Could anyone point me some code for troubleshooting that? The main app was all fine about that but now on the update my app was rejected for the second time for the same reason.

Here is my code for that

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);}

@end
```

But it's npt working

Comment: Well, does holding the iPad/iPhone 180 degrees of the current orientation work? If not, then fix that.

Comment: what? Home button up is mandatory on iPhone? Since when? This is weird especially because apple puts `return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);` into shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in their templates.

Comment: Yeah i wan't to support only those two orientations

Comment: that's what i'm asking my self too!

Comment: well it looks like "For more information, please review the Aim to Support All Orientations section of the iOS Human Interface Guidelines." they don't want you too... :/

Comment: i don't understand that, they rejected my app what the don't want me too?

Comment: and this is for an iPhone only app? Not one that is universal? A while ago (as in 2 years ago when I read those HIG) I read specifically that users would be confused if they had to rotate their phone by 180 deg so they could answer a call and therefor portrait upside down should not be used on iPhone.

Comment: it's a universal app you think that is the problem?

Comment: universal app changes everything. so they talk about the rotation on the iPad.

Comment: You tagged your question with the iPhone tag, so we assumed it is an iPhone only app. Please update your question.

Comment: so what should i change to fix that only on ipad is the problem you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you said it's an universal app everything becomes clear.

On iPads you have to support all interface orientations, especially all 180 degree variants. So if you support portrait you have to support portrait upside down too. If you support landscape left you have to support landscape right too.

On iPhones there is no need to support portrait upside down. That's the default apple puts into their UIViewController templates.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // on iPad support all orientations
        return YES;
    } else {
        // on iPhone/iPod support all orientations except Portrait Upside Down
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }
    return NO;
}
```

**put that into every view controller in your app.**

Comment: ok does that code work in simulator too?

Comment: no it doesn't work in simulator and have no ipad to test it

Comment: put that code in all your viewControllers. It's not enough to put it in a single one if you are using a UITabBarController. Search for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in your project and check every single method you find. If one of them returns only YES for portrait you can't rotate to portrait upside down

Comment: Matthias you saved my life man thanks a lot you rock!!!

Comment: one more question on iphone do i have to support multiple orientations too?

Comment: on iPhone portrait only is okay. There are thousands of apps that do this.

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated in iOS6

Answer (score 3):

Override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` in your view controller(s)

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest fixing "Specifically, we noticed your app only supported the top up variant of the portrait orientation, but not the bottom up variation." and testing it out of IOS5, or which ever iOS version you are putting the app out there. 
Thats pretty much the only issue.

Maybe post your orientation code and we can fix it for you.

Anyways questions like this are too localized for SO. Please read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for questions that are aimed for SO. Thanks

Comment: I understand that there is an SO sister site for iOS development although I forget what it is offhand...

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/ ? I dont think it has an iOS dev site

Comment: this would probably be ontopic on the [app stores site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores?referrer=jcBbxTFsYbhSPTdluUKgFA2) (which doesn't exist _yet_)

Comment: @sch I haven't tested it but i thought it was standard that if you specified that you only want landscape orientation and used that code i did have, it would autoflip it. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 2):

You should accept both portrait orientations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

This code accepts both `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` and `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`.

**Edit**

Now that you mention that the app is universal, then yes, Apple HIG recommend that iPad apps support all orientations (4) or at least both landscape or both portrait orientations (2).

If you want the app to support all orientations on the iPad:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

return YES;
```

If you want the app to support only portrait orientations

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to write this below your post, but does your application rotate when you rotate the view upside down? I interpreted Apple's response as you currently do not support it.

Here is the documentation which talks about handling the view, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Under the 'Handling View Rotations' you must support the enum types referenced here, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait

I believe something like this comes in the one of the base examples, so this is more or less what they aiming for.

Best of luck, cheers.

```
/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/
```

Comment: no my app doesn't rotate so where is the problem i can't understand!