# UIAlertView and Upside Orientation

Tags: ios, xamarin

The entire interface is rotating correctly for all possible screen orientations. But when UIAlertView is shown it's not rotated to upside down orientation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about an iPhone app or an iPad app? Since upside down orientation on an iPhone app will probably get you rejected from the App Store: [Past question about rejection from the App Store due to orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625206/apple-app-rejection-reason).

If this is an iPhone issue that you're referring to, and you shouldn't allow upside down orientation support, try removing it, as explained in the attached post, as see if it resolves your issue.

Comment: It is an iPhone app. Are you sure that if i allow Upside down orientation for iPhone app , App will get rejected?

Comment: There are exceptions, like navigation apps that should be able to display the map even if the device is upside down while charging in the car, but they get special approvals for that. For us "regular developers", upside down orientation is out of the question for iPhone apps

Comment: Thanks for saving me :)